# Counting multi-select picklist selections in a formula

Tags: formula, formula-field

I would like to ask something about FORMULAS.

I have a multipick list field where the user select one or more options(text), i would like to count how many options he select and multiple that for one value...how can i do that?i don t find any function that let me count the number of values that he select...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8):

[This blog](http://mysalesforcecode.blogspot.ie/2010/06/count-selected-items-in-multipicklist.html) gives an example of how to do this. The idea is that the formula knows all the possible values of the picklist. Example: if your multi-select field was called Colors and had 3 possible values in it then the formula would be:

```
IF(INCLUDES(Colors__c, 'Red'), 1, 0) 
+ IF(INCLUDES(Colors__c, 'Green'), 1, 0) 
+ IF(INCLUDES(Colors__c, 'Blue'), 1, 0)
```

The downside of this is that the formula needs to be kept in sync with the picklist values. For Example if you added a 4th Color called Yellow then the above formula wouldnt count this value.

Implementing this in a trigger may be a better solution as you will be able to add/remove/edit the picklist values without having to modify the logic that does the count. The logic would be something like:

```
trigger CountingValues on MyObject__c (before insert, before update) {

    if (Trigger.isUpdate) {
        for (MyObject__c mo : Trigger.new) {
            if (mo.Colors__c != Trigger.oldMap.get(mo.Id).Colors__c) {
                if (String.isNotBlank(mo.Colors__c) {
                    List<String> colors = mo.Colors__c.split(';');
                    mo.ColorsCount__c = colors.size();
                } else {
                    mo.ColorsCount__c = 0;
                }
            }
        }
     }
}
```

The above code is untested but it will give you an idea of how to implement the trigger

Comment: You think that the only option? because he can select for a lot of fields and if he add a new filed we will need to change the formula.... but thank you very much Bart

Comment: I will update my answer with the Trigger solution as well. I dont know any other way to do it with a formula

Comment: Sorry for the drive-by comment, by if Colors__c is not null, the size() is not zero. Fields are always null when empty, and never have size() of 0.

Answer (score 0):

This is awesome. I have a use case where we need to have counters for multiple Objects and Multi-Select Fields.

I took the trigger code from above and used it in a dynamic class. This way you can call a method, and pass the Object, Multi-Select and Counter Fields in from a trigger. This allows you to replicate the functionality across many Fields and Objects

Class

```
public with sharing class MultiSelectCounter {

public void getCount(string mspField, string objectName, list<string> recordIDs, string counterField){
    list<sObject> recUpdates = new list<sObject>();
    list<sObject> recQuery = database.query('Select ID, '+mspField+', '+counterField+' FROM '+objectName+' WHERE ID IN :recordIDs');    
        for(sObject sObj : recQuery){
            if(String.isNotBlank(String.valueOf(sObj.get(mspField)))){
                List<String> mspSize = String.valueOf(sObj.get(mspField)).split(';');
                sObj.put(counterField, mspSize.size());
                recUpdates.add(sObj);
            }
            else{
                sObj.put(counterField, 0);
                recUpdates.add(sObj);
            }
        }
        update recUpdates;
}
}
```

Trigger on Case where I'm looking at two Multi-Select Fields:

```
Activities_Skill_Types_Completed__c, Activities_Skill_Types_Counter__c
```

and two Counter Fields:

```
of_Activities_Skill_Types_Completed__c, of_Activities_Skill_Types_Started__c
```

Full Trigger Code

```
trigger MultiSelectCounterCase on Case (after insert, after update) {

list<String> startedIDs = new list<String>();
list<String> completedIDs = new list<String>();

list<Case> newCases = [SELECT ID, Activities_Skill_Types_Started__c, Activities_Skill_Types_Completed__c, Of_Activities_Skill_Types_Started__c, Of_Activities_Skill_Types_Completed__c FROM Case WHERE ID IN :trigger.new];
if(trigger.isUpdate){
    for(Case newCase : newCases){
        Case oldCase = trigger.OldMap.get(newCase.ID);
        if(oldCase.Activities_Skill_Types_Started__c != newCase.Activities_Skill_Types_Started__c){
            startedIDs.add(newCase.ID);
        }
        if(oldCase.Activities_Skill_Types_Completed__c != newCase.Activities_Skill_Types_Completed__c){
            completedIDs.add(newCase.ID);
        } 
    }

}
if(trigger.isInsert){
    for(Case newCase: newCases){
        if(newCase.Activities_Skill_Types_Started__c != null){
            startedIDs.add(newCase.ID);
        }
        if(newCase.Activities_Skill_Types_Completed__c != null){
            completedIDs.add(newCase.ID);
        }
    }       
}
MultiSelectCounter msc = new MultiSelectCounter();
msc.getCount('activities_skill_types_started__c', 'case', startedIDs, 'of_activities_skill_types_started__c' );
msc.getCount('activities_skill_types_completed__c', 'case', completedIDs, 'of_activities_skill_types_completed__c' );

}
```