# How to Find the Count of Multi-Select Picklist?

Tags: apex, trigger, picklist, multi-select, before-trigger

I was searching for a method to find the count of selected multi-select picklist. My aim is to select multiple options for Known-Languages in a Drop down and to display the selected count in a Counter and reflect the changes of count based on selection from multi-select picklist using Insert-Update before trigger.

But couldn't able to find a direct one  and was able to see some workaround way using a `List` and the `split` method using `';'` and it worked well ([Referred Link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/20959/counting-multi-select-picklist-selections-in-a-formula))

I have written my trigger as below and it worked fine with my test cases.

```
trigger AccountMultiselect on Account (before insert, before update) {
    for(Account acc:Trigger.new){
        if(String.isNotBlank(acc.Languages_Known__c)){
            List<String> Langs = acc.Languages_Known__c.split(';');
            acc.Counter__c     = Langs.size();
        } else {
            acc.Counter__c     = 0;
        } 

    }
}
```

Can some one let me know

1. Are there any direct methods to check the count instead of `List` and `split` ? This approach was suggested somewhere 2013 and just want to know any new methods available recently.
2. Does the above code have any loopholes?

Comment: As a one-liner, for performance: `acc.Counter__c = acc.Languages_Known__c == null? 0: acc.Languages_Known__c.split(';').size();`, but there's nothing wrong with the trigger as is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any direct methods to check the count instead of List and Split method using ';'

Nope, splitting by semicolon and calling `size()` on the resulting list is pretty much it. There are probably one or two other ways (1 + # of semicolons), but the method you're using now is likely the simplest.

> Does the above code have any loop holes?

Probably not. It's a short piece of code that uses pretty common (and standard) methods.

Generally speaking, having a good suite of unit tests is important. Having them would increase one's confidence that a piece of code will behave as expected under a variety of circumstances.

If you don't have tests that verify the following cases, I'd suggest writing tests to cover these cases:

- What happens when `Languages_Known__c` is null?
- What happens when `Languages_Known__c` is empty (but not null)?
- Do you get a count of 1 when `Languages_Known__c` only selects one option (no semicolons)?
- Do you get a count of 2 when `Languages_Known__c` selects two options?
- What happens when `Languages_Known__c` only contains semicolons?
- What happens when `Languages_Known__c` contains duplicate selections?

The second, fifth, and sixth cases shouldn't occur in normal use, but can happen if some other code is writing the value of `Languages_Known__c` (which is just a semicolon-delimited string, after all).

Comment: 2, 5, and 6 will not occur in Trigger.new, though. There's no practical point in testing those, but otherwise a good answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you **don't have much values** in your multi-picklist you could do it with a formula field(Number) :

```
IF(INCLUDES(Languages_Known__c,"ENGLISH"), 1 , 0) +
IF(INCLUDES(Languages_Known__c,"FRENCH"), 1 , 0) +
IF(INCLUDES(Languages_Known__c,"SPANISH"), 1 , 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's the function `PICKLISTCOUNT` for formulas. So you can write a formula field like so:

```
PICKLISTCOUNT(Languages_Known__c)
```

I understand it wasn't available when you asked this question. It's new as of, I believe, Winter 23